# Rename file with NPM

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json

Is there a way to rename a single file in npm scripts? I want to prepare files for distribution, but I need the built files to be named differently than they are in the source...

I have tried orn, but that only seems to work on the command line, not as an npm script. I'm specifically looking to just add a cross-platform dependency to do my project, rather than writing my own javascript script to copy files over.

My ideal solution is something I can include in the `package.json`, as a one line command, e.g. `rename old-file-name new-file-name`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the npm library [cash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cash) offers several basic command line utilities that can be run as a single line command from a package.json. For renaming, you can use the sub-package [cash-mv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cash-mv) to rename a specific file.

Answer (score 4):

Sure. `npm script` can run any node js file you want.

For example:

```
require('fs').rename(oldPath,newPath)
```

More Info:

- https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_rename_oldpath_newpath_callback
- https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts

Comment: Sorry, should've been more clear, I just want something I can include in my package.json, as a single line command. However, this is pretty succinct.

Comment: you can include this as a script, just prepend "node -e": `node -e require('fs').rename(oldPath,newPath)`

Comment: @russa any ideas on this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54438734/how-to-rename-file-with-npm-script ?

Comment: since `node` version 10.x the 3rd parameter (callback) for `rename()` is not optional anymore -- you could either add a callback, or you could use `renameSync(oldPath, newPath)` instead which does not require a callback-parameter (and is synchronous)

Answer (score 0):

Configure the scripts section of your package.json as follows:

```
"scripts": {
  "rename": "node -e \"require('fs').rename('C:/abc.text', 'C:/xyz.text', function(err) { if (err) console.log(err); console.log('File renamed!') })\""
},
```

Then run the following npm command:

```
npm run copy-and-rename
```

On successful completion you should see the following logged to the console after the file has been copied and renamed:

`File successfully renamed!`