# How to rename file with npm script

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-scripts

I am using [copyfiles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copyfiles) as an npm `scirpt` `copyfiles -u 2 /src/app/conf.dev.json dist/config/`  but in the end I want to get the file renamed

How would you rename the input file in to something like `conf.json` ?

I check the docs and didn't find that it is possible to achieve with `copyfiles`.
Any thoughts?

**UPDATE**:
I follow up to this [Rename file with NPM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35258871/rename-file-with-npm) but getting an error when do `npm run copy`:

```
"copy": "copyfiles -u 2 /src/app/conf.dev.json dist/config/ && node -e require('fs').rename('dist/config/conf.prod.json','dist/config/conf.json')"
```

> fs.js:137
>       throw new ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK();
>       ^
>
> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Below are a couple of solutions to successfully meet your requirement:

### Solution A

As noted in [@vitorlui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6103905/vitorlui)'s answer the callback parameter is mandatory when using the nodejs built-in [fs.rename()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_rename_oldpath_newpath_callback).

Also when utilizing the `node -e` command via a npm script it is necessary to wrap the script to evaluate in JSON escaped double quotes, i.e. `\"...\"`.

1. For instance, configure the `scripts` section of your *package.json* as follows:

   ```json
   "scripts": {
     "rename": "node -e \"require('fs').rename('dist/config/conf.dev.json', 'dist/config/conf.json', function(err) { if (err) console.log(err); console.log('File successfully renamed!') })\"",
     "copy": "copyfiles -u 2 \"src/app/conf.dev.json\" \"dist/config/\"",
     "copy-and-rename": "npm run copy && npm run rename"
   },
   ```
2. Then run the following npm command:

   ```
   npm run copy-and-rename
   ```
3. On successful completion you should see the following logged to the console after the file has been copied and renamed:

   > `File successfully renamed!`

---

### Solution B

You could also consider installing and utilizing [renamer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/renamer) for renaming the file. This may be beneficial if your renaming requirements become more complex than the example provided in your question, or if you want something less verbose than *Solution A*.

#### Install and check which version:

1. `cd` to your project directory and install `renamer` by running the following command:

   ```
   npm i -D renamer
   ```
2. Then run the following command to check which version of `renamer` was installed.

   ```
   npm ls renamer
   ```

---

**Note:** *The reason I ask you to check which version was installed is because this will determine which of the following `renamer` commands you should utilize. It differs slightly if the version installed is <0.7.0 or >=0.7.0:*

---

#### If the version of renamer installed is <0.7.0

1. Set the `scripts` section of your *package.json* to the following:

   ```json
   "scripts": {
     "rename": "renamer --dry-run -f --regex \"^conf.dev.json$\" -r \"conf.json\" \"dist/config/*\"",
     "copy": "copyfiles -u 2 \"src/app/conf.dev.json\" \"dist/config/\"",
     "copy-and-rename": "npm run copy && npm run rename"
   },
   ```
2. Then run the following `npm` command:

   ```
   npm run copy-and-rename
   ```
3. You should see something like the following logged to your console;

   > `√ dist\config\conf.dev.json -> dist\config\conf.json`

   to indicate which pathname was changed.
4. You'll also notice that the actual filename of the copied file hasn't changed, that's because we included the `--dry-run` option. Simply ***omit the `--dry-run` option from your script and run the command*** again for the actual file name to be changed.

---

#### If the version of renamer installed is >=0.7.0

There was a breaking change since v0.7.0 which included the removal of the `--regex` option *(see [here](https://github.com/75lb/renamer/releases) for further info)*. A regular expression literal is now provided since this version instead.

This change to the API results in the `rename` script, (as previously shown), needing to be redefined as follows:

```
"rename": "renamer -f \"/^conf.dev.json$/\" -r \"conf.json\" \"dist/config/*\"",
                        ^               ^
```

**Note:** The `--regex` option has been omitted and a regexp is now a literal, i.e. it's now wrapped in a leading and trailing forward slash. Also, in this example the `--dry-run` option was removed, so reinstate it for testing purposes.

---

### Additional Notes

- For both *Solution A* and *Solution B*, the copying and renaming logic has been added to separate npm scripts, (namely `copy` and `rename` respectively) for clarity of explanation. However you can chain the two commands using the `&&` operator instead to form one npm script - the single line will be rather long though :)
- For *Solution B*, I often utilize version `0.6.1` of `renamer`, so I run; `npm i -D renamer@0.6.1` to install, as I typically have older versions of nodejs to support. In which case I utilize the `--regex` flag as per the example shown in the aforementioned sub section titled: *"If the version of renamer installed is <0.7.0"*.

Comment: You may also want to look at [shx](https://github.com/shelljs/shx). It's  basically `shelljs` but for commands in npm package scripts, so it's portable/cross-platform. Looks like you could do it with one single `shx mv ....` command. Very terse ;)

Comment: Doing something as extreme as renaming a file really should require compiling the kernel from scratch.

Comment: @DemPilafian - I don't consider renaming a file on your local file system as _"extreme"_. Why should it _"require compiling the kernel from scratch"_ ? ... I don't understand the point you are raising within the context of this Q&A.

Comment: RobC, It was just a sarcastic comment about how something that should be extraordinarily simple, like renaming a file, ends up being quite convoluted and requires a two page answer.

Answer (score 3):

You must define the callback function:

```
fs.rename('oldFile.txt', 'newFile.txt', (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Rename complete!');
});
```

Something like that:

```
"copy": "copyfiles -u 2 /src/app/conf.dev.json dist/config/ && node -e require('fs').rename('dist/config/conf.prod.json','dist/config/conf.json' , (err) => { (err? console.log(err) : console.log('Rename complete!') ) } )"
```

@see https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_rename_oldpath_newpath_callback

Answer (score 1):

You can use this lib.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/move-file just move if to the "new name"

Comment: @Suxio How would you use move-file in an npm script? Could you provide an example, please?

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

You can utilize an npm package called [move-file-cli](https://github.com/sindresorhus/move-file-cli) that allows renaming files via (cross-platform) CLI, then use the command "move-file" in your npm script to rename files

### Installation

`npm install move-file-cli`

### Utilization

`move-file <source-path> <destination-path>`

> Optional - Don't overwrite an existing destination file: --no-overwrite