# How can I get npm to create a .min.css file from scss?

Tags: css, npm, sass, npm-scripts

I'm automatically compiling css from scss using a json script, but it's removing ".min" from the suffix. This is the terminal output which shows the script that I'm running and the file that is rendering:

```
PS C:\Projects\myproject> npm run globalscss

> myproject@1.0.0 globalscss C:\Projects\myproject
> node-sass -w scss/usn-global.scss -o css css/usn-global.min.css --output-style compressed

=> changed: C:\Projects\myproject\scss\usn-global.scss
Rendering Complete, saving .css file...
Wrote CSS to C:\Projects\myproject\css\usn-global.css
```

I'm expecting to see the script write to C:\Projects\myproject\css\usn-global.min.css

But the script is writing to C:\Projects\myproject\css\usn-global.css

Is there a problem with having a double suffix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you are using the `-o, --output` flag, node-sass will always compile the input file to the given output directory with the same filename.

If you omit the output flag and pipe the output to the folder instead, it's possible to target the suffixed filename you want.

Example:

```
node-sass --output-style compressed scss/usn-global.scss > css/usn-global.min.css
```

This will work as long as the `css` folder exists.

However it seems according to [this issue](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2099) that it's not possible to combine this command with the `-w, --watch` flag. There are options to [renaming files with npm scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54438734/how-to-rename-file-with-npm-script) though.

If you stick to your current workflow with the watcher intact, you can add another npm script to your `package.json` file, maybe something like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "rename": "node -e \"require('fs').rename('css/usn-global.css', 'css/usn-global.min.css', function(err) { if (err) console.log(err); console.log('CSS file renamed with .min suffix!') })\""
}
```

...meaning that when you're done CSS-ing, you'd need to run `npm run rename` to get the correct filename.